# Como cuento solo los registros con datos de diferentes columnas en MySql

Tags: php, mysql

deseo contar los datos de tres columnas diferentes en la misma tabla, el código no me funciona y creo que tengo un error de sintaxis... pero no lo veo... gracias por su ayuda.

Esta es la DB:
[image: Tabla vehiculos, con 50 líneas pero solo 4 tienen registros...]

// Consulta SQL

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(vehiculo1) AS cuenta1, COUNT(vehiculo2) AS cuenta2, COUNT(vehiculo3) AS cuenta3 FROM vehiculos WHERE vehiculo1 IS NOT NULL AND vehiculo2 IS NOT NULL AND vehiculo3 IS NOT NULL AND idnitu = $id";
```

// Ejecuto la consulta

```
$resultadov = $db->query($sql);
```

// Verifico si hay resultados y mostrar el conteo

```
if ($resultadov->num_rows > 0) {
    $fila = $resultadov->fetch_assoc();
    $conteo1 = $fila['cuenta1'];
    $conteo2 = $fila['cuenta2'];
    $conteo3 = $fila['cuenta3'];
    echo "Conteo Columna 1: " . $conteo1 . "<br>";
    echo "Conteo Columna 2: " . $conteo2 . "<br>";
    echo "Conteo Columna 3: " . $conteo3 . "<br>";
} else {
    echo "No se encontraron resultados.";
}
```

Pero el resultado en cada columna es = 50...

[image: El resultado es 50... pero no es correcto]
y lo correcto sería que en 'vehiculo1 = 4', 'vehiculo2 = 1' y 'vehiculo3 = 0'

Gracias por la ayuda...

Comment: Count no funciona asi.. count cuenta si esta o no la fila.. independientemente del resultado de la misma.. no ve contenidos.. ve filas... probaste ver que trae ese query sin el count?

Comment: @gbianchi si haces `count(columna)` si que ve el contenido, pues cuenta solamente los valores que no son nulos. `count(*)` o `count(1)` si que no ven contenidos y cuentan filas completas. Mira mi respuesta.

Comment: @jachguate por eso.. cuenta todas sus filas, segun las condiciones que puso ;)

Answer (score 1):

El error está en la cláusula `where` de tu sentencia SQL.

A ojo de buen cubero, diría que te falta agregar alguna condición y además quitar o cambiar otras, pero no puedo decir exactamente cuál es y creo que es importante que comprendas qué es lo que está pasando para que puedas resolverlo tú mismo.

Comienzo por explicarte que en SQL, `count()` cuenta precisamente aquellos registros dónde el valor no sea nulo. (Más adelante volveremos a este punto y haremos una demostración).

Por otro lado, tú estás tomando en cuenta solamente registros que no tengan ningún valor nulo en los campos que estás queriendo contar, por lo que lo lógico es que los 3 contadores te devuelvan lo mismo.

Tu consulta SQL es así:

```sql
SELECT   COUNT(vehiculo1) AS cuenta1
       , COUNT(vehiculo2) AS cuenta2
       , COUNT(vehiculo3) AS cuenta3 
  FROM vehiculos 
 WHERE vehiculo1 IS NOT NULL 
   AND vehiculo2 IS NOT NULL 
   AND vehiculo3 IS NOT NULL 
   AND idnitu = $id
```

Si observas las condiciones del where, el motor te devolverá solamente las filas dónde ninguno de los 3 campos sea nulo y además se cumpla la igualdad del campo `idnitu`.

Te invito a usar tu cliente de MySQL favorito y ejecutar esta consulta:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM vehiculos 
 WHERE vehiculo1 IS NOT NULL 
   AND vehiculo2 IS NOT NULL 
   AND vehiculo3 IS NOT NULL 
   AND idnitu = 10
```

Sustituye el `10` por el valor del ID con el que estás haciendo las pruebas, y verás que la consulta va a devolver exactamente 50 filas.

Esta parte me hace pensar que falta agregar algunas condiciones al `where`, dado que tu esperas valores más pequeños (menos filas).

Luego, si quieres ver valores distintos de los contadores, necesitas cambiar las condiciones de la consulta con respecto a las columnas que cuentas. Si quieres obtener las filas donde haya al menos un vehículo que contar, podría ser:

```sql
SELECT   COUNT(vehiculo1) AS cuenta1
       , COUNT(vehiculo2) AS cuenta2
       , COUNT(vehiculo3) AS cuenta3 
  FROM vehiculos 
 WHERE (    vehiculo1 IS NOT NULL 
         OR vehiculo2 IS NOT NULL 
         OR vehiculo3 IS NOT NULL 
       )
   AND idnitu = $id
   AND --las otras condiciones que hayas hallado que hacen falta
```

Observa que he utilizado un paréntesis para indicar la precedencia de los operadores. ESta consulta me va a *contar* todos los registros que tengan al menos un vehículo y cumplan con la igualdad del campo `idnitu`, más las otras condiciones que encuentres que hacían falta.

##Count() en general

Sobre el funcionamiento de `count()` he preparado un [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/x-ciTT-r) para que puedas comprobarlo en una estructura fuera de esto, es muy simple:

Una tabla de prueba con 3 campos:

```sql
create table prueba(vehiculo1 varchar(100), vehiculo2 varchar(100), vehiculo3 varchar(100))
```

En la cual insertamos algunos registros con distintos valores:

```sql
insert into prueba values 
  ("v1_1", null, null)
, (null, "v2_2", null)
, (null, null, "v3_3")
, ("v1_4", "v2_4", "v3_4")
, (null, null, null)
, (null, "v2_6", null)
  ;
```

Es decir, estos datos:

| vehiculo1 | vehiculo2 | vehiculo3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| v1_1 | null | null |
| null | v2_2 | null |
| null | null | v3_3 |
| v1_4 | v2_4 | v3_4 |
| null | null | null |
| null | v2_6 | null |

Y luego probamos *contar* los valores en los campos:

```
select count(vehiculo1), count(vehiculo2), count(vehiculo3) from prueba;
select count(vehiculo1), count(vehiculo2), count(vehiculo3) from prueba where vehiculo1 is not null and vehiculo2 is not null and vehiculo3 is not null;
```

Devuelven:

```
count(v1)  count(v2)  count(v3)
2          3          2
1          1          1
```

Respectivamente.

Observa como para la segunda consulta todos los contadores devuelven el mismo valor, pues es, en resumen, lo que le estamos pidiendo.

Comment: Gracias a @jachguate por tan excelente respuesta, muy fácil de comprender... sin embargo no me sigue funcionando....

Será que hay algún inconveniente que en mis campos vacios figura "empty" y en los tuyos "null"

Comment: @ivan: Bueno, un campo _vacío_ (hablando de SQL), no puede tener otra cosa que no sea `NULL`, que es el valor especial para representar ausencia de valor en el lenguaje. Si almacenas otra cosa en los campos, habría que hacer algo distinto. Supuse que lo que se ve era un artefacto de la representación de la información y no que esa era la información como tal. ¿Almacenas la cadena `'empty'`? Como sea que lo hagas, debieras editar la pregunta y dejar bien claro cómo funciona TU sistema (cualquier cosa fuera de lo estándar).

Comment: Hola, cree la DB en TablePlus y las tablas... y así figuran los campos... trate de cambiarlos a NULL pero no me lo permite....  esto altera el resultado?

Comment: Hola @jachguate ... Perfecto, reescribi los datos y coloque NULL en los campos vacíos...  Funciono perfecto....  Muchas gracias.

Comment: No sé qué es TablePlus, pero tu pregunta no lo menciona, ni las etiquetas. No sé que diferencia pueda haber hecho. Me alegra que pudieras resolver tu problema. Si ya todo funcionó, considera [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/21). Un saludo.

Comment: Hola... @jachguate correcto... faltaban condiciones en el WHERE y detallar más la consulta...  arriba publiqué la solución... muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

como para cerrar este hilo.
La solución de @jachguate funcionó inicialmente, pero una vez se guarda alguna modificación el mysql vuelve a llenar los campos como 'empty' y se daña la consulta.
La solución:

// Consulta SQL para vehiculos1

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(vehiculo1) AS cuenta1 
FROM vehiculos 
WHERE idnitu = '$id' 
AND vehiculo1 IS NOT NULL AND vehiculo1 != ''";
$resultado1 = $db->query($sql);
```

// Consulta SQL para vehiculos2

```
  $sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(vehiculo2) AS cuenta2
  FROM vehiculos 
  WHERE idnitu = '$id' 
  AND vehiculo2 IS NOT NULL AND vehiculo2 != ''";
  $resultado2 = $db->query($sql2);
```

// Consulta SQL para vehiculos 3

```
$sql3 = "SELECT COUNT(vehiculo3) AS cuenta3 
FROM vehiculos 
WHERE idnitu = '$id' 
AND vehiculo3 IS NOT NULL AND vehiculo3 != ''";
$resultado3 = $db->query($sql3);
```

Separé las consultas de cada columna y después sumé los totales...

// Verificar si hay resultados y mostrar el conteo

```
if ($resultado1->num_rows > 0) {
    $fila = $resultado1->fetch_assoc();
    $conteo1 = $fila['cuenta1'];
}
```

// Verificar si hay resultados y mostrar el conteo

```
if ($resultado2->num_rows > 0) {
  $fila = $resultado2->fetch_assoc();
  $conteo2 = $fila['cuenta2'];
}
```

// Verificar si hay resultados y mostrar el conteo

```
if ($resultado3->num_rows > 0) {
  $fila = $resultado3->fetch_assoc();
  $conteo3 = $fila['cuenta3'];
}
 else {
    
}
$num_registrosv = $conteo1 + $conteo2 + $conteo3;
```

No sé si técnicamente sea lo correcto... pero funcionó.
Gracias a todos